# 400, 502, 503 errors with Websockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, openshift

I am making a multiplayer game using Socket.io, Node.js, and Openshift. It was working for a while, but I made a few small changes and now something unrelated to what I changed has broken. When a second player tries to join the game, it boots everyone out, showing a 503 error for anyone else who goes on the site. For the second player, I get a lot of console errors including

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://avalon-evao.rhcloud.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=d5smykffy4EWHxgIAAAC' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

http://avalon-evao.rhcloud.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1421020862973-4&sid=d5smykffy4EWHxgIAAAC Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)

http://avalon-evao.rhcloud.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1421020865831-6&sid=d5smykffy4EWHxgIAAAC Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)

socket.io-1.2.0.js:2 WebSocket connection to 'ws://avalon-evao.rhcloud.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=c-fwcJaMkp_9rl5CAAAA' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

It works perfectly fine in localhost, but the real site is broken.

Here's what I've tried:

1. Using HTTPS. I still somehow get the 502 error.
2. Restarting the app using `rhc app restart`
3. Restarting the app using `rhc app force-stop rhc app start`
4. Checking the memory limit. I haven't hit it.
5. Connecting to websockets securely using the `{ secure: true }` option

What is causing these errors and how can I fix them?

Comment: What does your server side code look like for accepting websocket connections?

Answer (score 1):

Try:
ws://...rhcloud.com:8000/socket.io/...
wss://...rhcloud.com:8443/socket.io/...

https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/203263674-What-external-ports-are-available-on-OpenShift

Comment: It got rid of the console errors, but I'm still being booted out.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was looking at the logs wrong. When I figured out how to read the logs for rhc, I found an error in the database. I had changed the structure of the collections without dropping the database, so there were indexes to keys that no longer existed. Dropped the database, and the app works fine now.